# Receipt validation on iOS In-App-Purchase returns multiple transaction

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swift4

In-app purchase on sandbox mode returns multiple transactions on same product id.

Language Used: Swift 4.0

```
func validateAppReceipt(_ receipt: Data) {
    let base64encodedReceipt = receipt.base64EncodedString()
    print(base64encodedReceipt)
    let requestDictionary = ["receipt-data":base64encodedReceipt]
    guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(requestDictionary) else {  print("requestDictionary is not valid JSON");  return }
    do {
        let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDictionary)
        let validationURLString = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"  // this works but as noted above it's best to use your own trusted server
        guard let validationURL = URL(string: validationURLString) else { print("the validation url could not be created, unlikely error"); return }
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        var request = URLRequest(url: validationURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: requestData) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data , error == nil {
                do {
                    print(data)
                    let appReceiptJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                    print("success. here is the json representation of the app receipt: \(appReceiptJSON)")
                    self.getAppReceipt()
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
                }
            } else {
                print("the upload task returned an error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Response:

[image: Response:]

Questions:

- Why I am getting multiple transaction on same ID
- Whether this response is correct or not
- If it is correct, which ID to validate

I tried some links from apple and  stack overflow but still have doubts in understanding this. Can someone please describe me about all these.

Comment: Hi, where do we need to implement this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have implemented auto renewable in app purchase.
Your response is proper.

**Why I am getting multiple transaction on same ID**

As in your response transaction performed for auto renew product at every 5 minutes(Sandbox environment renew product in 5 minutes instead of 1 month in App Store).

**Whether this response is correct or not**

Yes

**If it is correct, which ID to validate**

You have to get all the transaction for your product id `tfc.premium.subscription` and then grab last object and use it as your latest/last transaction.

Read this [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW8) for proper understanding.

> The behavior of auto-renewable subscriptions differs between the
>   testing environment and the production environment.
>
> In the testing environment, subscription renewals happen at an
>   accelerated rate, and auto-renewable subscriptions renew a maximum of
>   six times per day. This enables you to test how your app handles a
>   subscription renewal, a subscription lapse, and a subscription history
>   that includes gaps. See Testing Auto-Renewable Subscriptions in the
>   In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect to learn about
>   the subscription durations for testing.
>
> Because of the accelerated expiration and renewal rates, a
>   subscription can expire before the system tries to renew the
>   subscription, leaving a small lapse in the subscription period. Such
>   lapses are also possible in production for a variety of reasons—make
>   sure your app handles them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is 5 mins gap, Is it default for sandbox ? and if Yes, can we increase the duration??

Comment: No, this is default to check auto renewable behavior in sandbox. You can not increase this time.

Comment: I don't know exact but it may renew almost  6 time. Try to go through this link as Auto renewable In App Purchase it bit tricky to test.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW8

Comment: Quite useful. I had read that article at first but had no idea what apple was raving about.

Answer (score 0):

You are using auto renewable subscriptions. There will be one receipt for every auto-renew or renew of the subscription.

So generally, if subscription has renewed 5 times then there will be 5 receipts in the sandbox environment and 6 in real environment (production environment, downloaded from AppStore). Because an receipt is generated for the app downloaded or purchased from the AppStore as well.

Comment: Thanks @Prateek Sujaina for your response. I understood :)