# Shall I get Receipt for cancelled Auto renewable subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

let say I purchase one month auto renewable subscription. I use product for 3 month, in 3rd month I cancel subscription. Now my question is can I get receipt for last two month transaction?

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are asking; The two subscription events will appear as in app purchases in the app receipt.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of receipt when working with iap is not the same as the general concept of receipts. You don't get a new receipt for each transaction. Your app only has one receipt. Each time you auto renewable subscription renews your app receipt will get updated with a new transaction.

> The receipt for an application or in-app purchase is a record of the
>   sale of the application and of any in-app purchases made from within
>   the application.

Comment: How can I know that from how many months user subscribed my iap subscription?

Comment: I think this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806158/receipt-validation-on-ios-in-app-purchase-returns-multiple-transaction